# net6.0 backward compatibility

Tags: .net, .net-6.0, packagereference

Is net6.0 compatible with net5.0 targeted packages? Could not find the answer easily accessible on google.

We have a newly upgraded project targeting net6

```
<TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
```

with a `PackageReference`

```
<PackageReference Include="SonarAnalyzer.CSharp" Version="8.*" />
```

and we get
[image]

is this supported or supposed to work?

As an additional piece of information, this is .net6 arm64

Comment: https://community.sonarsource.com/t/does-sonar-scanner-support-net-6/50365/2

Comment: Thanks. I’m asking a broader question. It sounds like the answer is no, but do net6 projects not support referencing net5 projects? If no, does this apply to all packages? Just tool packages?

Comment: Related: [.NET6 vs .NET Core 3.1 compatibility](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72532363/1497596)